# sphinxsearch pid file empty and netstat reports nothing

Tags: ubuntu, sphinx, ubuntu-10.04

Installed SphinxSearch on Ubuntu 10.04.

Every time I start it, the pid file (/var/run/searchd.pid) is a blank file. I can restart the service for a few seconds and then I get 'restart: Unknown instance:'

Also, SphinxSearch does not show up under 'netstat | grep 9312'.

Below is the searchd portion of my config file.

```
searchd
{
   listen = 9312
   log = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
   query_log = /var/log/sphinxsearch/log/query.log
   read_timeout = 5
   max_children = 30
   pid_file = /var/run/searchd.pid
   max_matches = 1000
   seamless_rotate = 1
   preopen_indexes = 0
   unlink_old = 1
}
```

and /etc/init/sphinxsearch.conf looks like

```
# SphinxSearch Service

description     "SphinxSearch Daemon"
author          "Andrey Aksyonoff <shodan@sphinxsearch.com>"

start on (net-device-up
          and local-filesystems
          and runlevel [2345])
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
respawn limit 10 35

# The default of 5 seconds is too low if we have rt indices and have to flush them
kill timeout 30

env DEFAULTFILE="/etc/default/sphinxsearch"
pre-start script
    if [ -f "$DEFAULTFILE" ]; then
        . "$DEFAULTFILE"
    fi
    if [ "z$START" != "zyes" ]; then
        stop
        logger "To enable sphinxsearch, edit /etc/default/sphinxsearch and set START=yes"
        exit 0
    fi
    if [ ! -f /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf ]; then
        logger "Please create an /etc/sphinxsearch/sphinx.conf configuration file."
        logger "Templates are in the /etc/sphinxsearch/ directory."
        exit 0
    fi
end script

exec /usr/bin/searchd --nodetach
```

Comment: What does your `/etc/init/whatever` config file look like?

Comment: `/etc/init.d/sphinxsearch` now included above

Comment: That's just the compatibility wrapper, not the `/etc/init/sphinxsearch` job config file...

Comment: ahh, edited to be /etc/init/sphinxsearch.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a little searching, this issue was simply caused by an invalid path to the log files. Nothing was ever reported that the logs could not be accessed...